# Is mvnrepository gradle line invalid?

Tags: gradle

For quite a while now, I have seen lines like this for gradle in mvnrepository

```
 org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.7.Final
```

I never got that line to work.  Does it work at all?  I am kind of sick of not being able to cut and paste from mvnrepository, so is there a way to use that line?

What I use right now is this:

```
 compile group: 'org.hibernate',        name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.7.Final'
```

Just tired of modifying it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the line in quotes, and it will work. For example, `compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.7.Final'`. Alternatively, use the "Grails" notation from http://search.maven.org.